# GUI component for displaying chat messages?

Tags: user-interface, gwt, scrollbar, chat

I'm searching for a gwt component with the following properties:

-Able to display Strings in a structured way, ie. username and message in seperate columns
-providing control over the scrollbar

In essence I'd like to have a component able to display more than simple strings and that auto scrolls to the bottom.

At first I used a simple textarea which fails to satisfy my first requirements. Additionaly I failed to implement the autoscroll to the bottom. 
Are there any components which accomplish those features? Or if not, how could I create a similar component?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom widget with the below or similar hierarchy,

> - **Vertical Panel/Dock Panel:** The outer container.
>
>   - **Header Panel**: A `horizontal panel` with width set to 100% and add the      required info. If using `Dock Panel`, set it to `North`
>   - **Scroll Panel** : To get the infinite scroll and set its width to 100%
>
>     - **Horizontal Panel(s)** : One panel for each chat string.